# Java:enhanced for loop can not convert object to class error

Tags: java

I need to draw restart button in the screen for my dice , but when using the for loop enhanced,

```
 public class DiceGameModel {
--------------------------------
-------------------------------
   public void reset() {
        this.playerNumber = 0;
       for(PlayerModel player : players)  {
           player.reset();
        }
    }
-------------------------
----------------------------
}
```

netbean returns object can not be converted to playermodel,is a a class that contains the reset method.

```
package dicemodel;    

public class PlayerModel {    
----------------------    
--------------------    
 public void reset() {    
        this.numberOfRolls = 0;    
        this.score = 0;    
        this.tempScore = 0;    
        this.dieRoll = 0;    
    }    
--------------------------    
----------------------------    
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `players`? And where's the enhanced for loop that doesn't work?

Comment: where are the players stored?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Which line is it on? What is the declaration of `players`?

Comment: Can you paste your not working code..

Comment: players it is an arraylist that is declared in the dicegame model class.

Comment: public class DiceGameModel {
 
        private static final int maxPlayers = 2;
        private int playerNumber;
        private List players;
        private Random random;
        public DiceGameModel() {
           this.players = new ArrayList();
            this.playerNumber = 0;
            this.random = new Random();
    }
 
       public void reset() {
            this.playerNumber = 0;
           PlayerModel player=new PlayerModel();
           for(int i=0;i<players.size();i++) {
               player.reset();
        }
    }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `players` is `ArrayList<PlayerModel> players = new ArrayList<>();`

Then your enhanced for loop should look like this:

```
for(PlayerModel player:players){
    player.reset();
}
```

With a standard for loop it would look like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
    players.get(i).reset();
    //this can be written in two lines like this:
    //PlayerModel tempModel = players.get(i);
    //tempModel.reset();
}
```

In enhanced for loop, each iteration returns an Object reference that you can work with directly. In standard for loop you iterate trough index values, that you can use to access different Objects inside the ArrayList using the .get() method...

Comment: the problem is i do have a reset method in my playermodel class and i'm using it

Comment: the thing is, you are not using it correctly, so you don't get the results that you expect

Comment: i included type for the generics now it's working properly

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
private List players;
```

to

```
private List<PlayerModel> players;
```

and change

```
this.players = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
this.players = new ArrayList<PlayerModel>();
```

`List` and `ArrayList` are generic classes. They should not be used without giving type information in angular brackets.